# remove some of the dynamic sidebar in wordpress admin side

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using evento word press theme.there are default sidebar widget in that theme.i don't want to visible in admin side.

in sidebar.php

```
<?php
    if(dynamic_sidebar ( 'main' ) ){            
    }
?>
```

in function.php

```
<?php
    define('_LIMIT_',10);
    /* google maps defines */
    define('MAP_LAT'    , 48.85680934671159 );
    define('MAP_LNG'    , 2.353348731994629 );
    define('MAP_CLAT'   , 48.85700699730661 );
    define('MAP_CLNG'   , 2.354121208190918 );
    define('MAP_ZOOM'   , 15 );
    define('DEFAULT_AVATAR'   , get_template_directory_uri()."/images/default_avatar.jpg" );
    define( '_TN_'      , get_current_theme() );
    define('BRAND'      , '' );
    define('ZIP_NAME'   , 'conference' );

    define('EXCERPT_CHAR_LEN'   , '600' );

    include 'lib/php/main.php';
    include 'lib/php/actions.register.php';
    include 'lib/php/menu.register.php';

    $content_width = 600;

    if( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ){
        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    }

    if( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ){
        add_image_size( 'slideshow'         , 920   , 300   , true );
        add_image_size( '62x62'             , 62    , 62    , true );
        add_image_size( '150xXXX'           , 150   , 999   );
        add_image_size( '300xXXX'           , 300   , 999   ); /*used for animated sponsors widget*/
        add_image_size( '600x200'           , 600   , 200   , true );
        add_image_size( '200x100'           , 200   , 100   , true ); /*gallery size*/
        add_image_size( '440x220'           , 440   , 220   , true ); /*used for 2 col gallery*/
        add_image_size( '280x140'           , 280   , 140   , true ); /*used for 3 col gallery*/

    }

    add_custom_background();
    add_editor_style('editor-style.css');

    /* Localization */
    load_theme_textdomain( 'cosmotheme' );
    load_theme_textdomain( 'cosmotheme' , get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

    if ( function_exists( 'load_child_theme_textdomain' ) ){
        load_child_theme_textdomain( 'cosmotheme' );
    }

    $pg = get_pages();
    $do = true;

    foreach( $pg as $p ){
        if( $p -> post_title == 'Registration' ){
            $do = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( $do ){
        $pages = array(
            'post_title' => 'Registration',
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'page'
        );

        wp_insert_post($pages);
    }

    /*New version check*/
    if(is_admin() && ini_get('allow_url_fopen') == '1'){
        function versionNotify(){
             echo api_call::compareVersions(); 
        }

        // Add hook for admin <head></head>
        add_action('admin_head', 'versionNotify');
    }

    /* Cosmothemes Backend link */
    function de_cosmotheme() {
        global $wp_admin_bar;
        if ( !is_super_admin() || !is_admin_bar_showing() ){
            return;
        }

        $current_theme_name = get_current_theme();
        $wp_admin_bar -> add_menu( array(
            'id' => 'cosmothemes',
            'parent' => '',
            'title' => $current_theme_name,
            'href' => admin_url( 'admin.php?page=cosmothemes__general' )
            ) );
    }
    add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'de_cosmotheme');



    add_custom_background();
    add_editor_style('editor-style.css');
?>
```

i don't know how to delete this one. please help me to delete that sidebar widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing or commenting this line: `add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'de_cosmotheme');`

I like to comment these things, instead of removing, so I have a reference to what the code 'used' to be, thus I'm always able to revert to the way it originally was coded.

---

**EDIT:**
*I found an older version of the theme, I hope it hasn't changed much*

Look up the file `\wp-content\themes\evento\lib\php\options.register.php` and comment or remove All the lines that look like `options::$menu['cosmothemes']['***']`

Pro tip: comment multiple lines by enclosing them with `/*` and `*/`

---

**EDIT2:**
I now think you meant the widgets whose names start with `Evento :` in the Appearance -> Widget menu in the wordpress admin.

Those are configured in `\wp-content\themes\evento\lib\php\actions.register.php` look for the lines that contain the function `register_widget` and comment or remove those.

---

**EDIT3:**

From the comments we derived that the widgets you actually meant were the sidebars added by `register_sidebar` again in `\wp-content\themes\evento\lib\php\actions.register.php` in my file they start on line `145`.

Comment: thanks for the reply.nothing happen when i comment or remove that line.

Comment: I updated my answer. To bad the bounty has sailed ;-)

Comment: I don't think I understood your question, I thought you meant you wanted to remove the Evento menu item. But now that I have looked more closely at the theme; I think you mean the widgets like 'Evento :' in `/wp-admin/widgets.php`, right?

Comment: i want to remove the sidebar widget that shown in admin side of wordpress like(front page top left,front page top middle,front page top right, etc..)

Comment: I think my new answer should do it then. Let me know how it goes.